# Can anybody help be for below link modified cursor

Tags: json, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

i modified my function to execute some json object

[cursor loop in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124490/cursor-loop-in-postgresql/40128819#40128819)

i have query which returns below result

```
SELECT asn."Id",asn."UserId",asn."ActivityId",pd."DataSourceId",ad."Dump"
   FROM "Development"."ActivitySession" as asn inner join "Development"."PersonDataSource" as pd on pd."UserId" = asn."UserId" inner join "Development"."ActivitySessionDump" as ad 
   on asn."Id"=ad."ActivitySessionId" where asn."CreatedAt" between now() - interval '5 days' and now() and asn."ActivityId"=1  and pd."DataSourceId"=1



Id                        UserId    ActId   DId  Dump
42594890910270849   42031336811660529   1   1   {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-17","value":"4023"}]}
42595097786975653   42031336811660529   1   1   {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-17","value":"4023"}]}
42597154682570183   42031336811660529   1   1   {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-17","value":"5388"}]}
42602824351352325   42031336811660529   1   1   {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-18","value":"0"}]}
42605659177354793   42031336811660529   1   1   {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-18","value":"0"}]}
42611328851117671   42031336811660529   1   1   {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-18","value":"0"}]}
```

i wrote one function below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ThirdPartyDataParse()
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
sessionid NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT asn."Id",asn."UserId",asn."ActivityId",pd."DataSourceId",ad."Dump"
   FROM "Development"."ActivitySession" as asn inner join "Development"."PersonDataSource" as pd on pd."UserId" = asn."UserId" inner join "Development"."ActivitySessionDump" as ad 
   on asn."Id"=ad."ActivitySessionId" where asn."CreatedAt" between now() - interval '5 days' and now() and asn."ActivityId"=1  and pd."DataSourceId"=1 for read only;
titles TEXT DEFAULT '';
rec record;
jsonrec record;
 BEGIN
 OPEN sessionid;
loop

FETCH sessionid INTO rec;
--raise notice '%d',rec."UserId";
   if not found then
        exit ;
   end if;
--titles := titles || ',' || rec."Dump";
 EXECUTE 'SELECT rec."Dump"::json#>''{activities-steps,0}''->>''value''' INTO jsonrec;
titles := titles || ',' || jsonrec."steps";
end loop;
return titles;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but i am unable to execute

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT rec."dump"::json#>''{activities-steps,0}''->>''value''' INTO jsonrec;
```

rec."dump" here is equal to {"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-17","value":"4023"}]}, so my query is like

```
SELECT '{"activities-steps":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-17","value":"4023"}]}'::json#>'{activities-steps,0}'->>'value' as steps;
```

but i am unable to execute this inside function error is:

```
Error in query: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "rec"
LINE 1: SELECT rec."Dump"::json#>'{activities-steps,0}'->>'value'
QUERY: SELECT rec."Dump"::json#>'{activities-steps,0}'->>'value'
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function thirdpartydataparse() line 19 at EXECUTE statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include a reference to a PL/pgSQL variable into the command string. The SQL parser does not know these variables, so it assumes that you are asking for an attribute `"Dump"` of a table `rec` and then complains if there is no `FROM` clause with that table.

You need to use `EXECUTE ... USING` like this:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT $1::json#>''{activities-steps,0}''->>''value'''
   INTO jsonrec USING rec."Dump";
```

Comment: i want to insert to table using EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO "Development"."ActivitySessionParameter" ("ActivitySessionId", "GameParameterId", "Value") VALUES (rec."Id",rec."ActivityId", jsonrec."steps")';
but error is Error in query: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "rec"